# How to increment arraylist String value by one

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

There are two for loops and I want to increment array list value that is of string type by one from inner for loop. How I can do that?

```
ArrayList<String> location; //Location and distanceInMiles are ArrayList<String> type and i have store some value into it. 
ArrayList<String> distanceInMiles;
for(String strloc : location){
    for(String strDist : distanceInMiles){
        System.out.println("For Location :" + strloc + "Zip code 30303" + "Distance in Miles:" + strDist);// After print the value i want to increment strDist value by one
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: a String is not a numerical value. You can't "increment" a String. make it an Integer, that you'll be able to increment

Comment: Note that a `String` is immutable .

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: Can you post sample String input and your wanted output ?

Answer (score 3):

```
    ArrayList<String> location; //Location and distanceInMiles are ArrayList<String> type and i have store some value into it.
    ArrayList<String> distanceInMiles;
    for(String strloc : location){
        ArrayList<String> clone = (ArrayList<String>) distanceInMiles.clone();
        distanceInMiles.clear();
        for(String strDist : clone){
            System.out.println("For Location :" + strloc + "Zip code 30303" + "Distance in Miles:" + strDist);// After print the value i want to increment strDist value by one
            distanceInMiles.add(Integer.parseInt(strDist) + 1 + "");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

String can't be incremented. So instead of passing `strDist` string to `PrintStream` you can parse the string to an `Integer` and do something like this:

```
System.out.printf("For Location : %s, Zip code 30303. Distance in Miles: %d%n", strloc, Integer.valueOf(strDist) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Order to do that incrementation you have to change the algorithm by inserting a String to floating point conversion steps (I assume that distances are represented as floating points with in the string).

```
List<String> location; 
List<String> distanceInMiles;

for(String strloc : location){
   for(int i=0; i < distanceInMiles.size(); i++){
       String strDist = distanceInMiles.get(i);
       System.out.println("For Location :" + strloc + "Zip code 30303" + "Distance in Miles:" + strDist);
       double value = Double.parseDouble(strDist);
       value++;
       distanceInMiles.set(i, String.valueOf(value));
       break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arraylists can hold a list of Object so you can't iterate through it with the type String.

After fixing this, the strDist will still not proceed to the next iteration this is because of the break statement, remove it.

You can do something like the following:

```
for (Object strDist : distanceInMiles) {

            System.out.println("For Location :" +strloc+ "Zip code 30303" + "Distance in Miles:" + strDist);// After print the value i want to increment strDist value by one

             // remove break
        }
```

Comment: I didn't say that

Comment: Well what did you mean by this: "Arraylists hold a list of Object so you can't iterate through it with the type String." ?? Also he clearly specified for his ArrayLists to hold String instances.

Comment: That it holds a list of objects doesn't mean that it can only contain objects, but I can see the confusion.

Comment: In the case of the question it is enough to iterate as I did as the arraylist holds a reference to the String object, unless I misunderstood the question.